# Initializing embedded struct when no control over parent initialization

Tags: go

I have a struct such:

```
type Parent struct {
  *WithContext
}

type WithContext struct {
  Ctx context.Context
}

func (wi *WithContext) SetContext(ctx context.Context) {
  // nil pointer
  wi.Ctx = ctx
}
```

Parent is initialized by some automated process (as apart of unmarshalling flow), so I cannot initialize the embedded WithContext struct,

Is there any way to avoid the nil pointer in the 'SetContext' func ? I tried overriding the pointer receiver but it doesn't have any effect,

Thanks,

Asaf.

Comment: Please provide more information - for example a small, complete working program that illustrates the problem. If you're saying that you're getting a nil-pointer panic just after your "nil pointer" comment, then you could trivially get around that by doing "if wi != nil { wi.Ctx = ct }" but why is your code calling SetContext on a nil object in the first place?

Comment: If some code by reflection creates p := Parent{}, p.SetContext(value) will cause nil, of course I can avoid nil by 'if wi != nil' but my question is whether or not it's possible to change what the address of the pointer receiver to a new instance. (such wi = &WithContext{})

Comment: The receiver parameter is just like any other parameter - if you change it, it changes the value locally but does not have any other side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, whatever is constructing the `Parent` struct should initialize it so it's in a usable state. But since you have no control over it, the next best thing is to have a piece of code that lets you set the `WithContext` pointer in `Parent`, by providing a member function on `Parent` or just a piece of code in your application to set it, since `WithContext` field is exported.